# Enable Textfield after Checkbox is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
echo ' 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="'.$data2["name"].'" value="'.$data2["name"].'" 
onclick="document.getElementById(numberof'.$data2["name"].').disabled=this.checked;"></td>

<td><input type="text" size="1" name="numberof'.$data2["name"].'"  value="1" " ></td>';
```

Hello!

I used the last solution in this question but it don't work.

[How to disable textbox depending on checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531552/how-to-disable-textbox-depending-on-checkbox-checked)

What can be wrong with it?

Best regards,
Susi :*

Comment: replace it, 
<td><input type="text" size="1" name="numberof'.$data2["name"].'"  value="1" " ></td>';
with
<td><input type="text" size="1" id="numberof'.$data2["name"].'" name="numberof'.$data2["name"].'"value ="1" ></td>';

your text input is missing ID

Comment: Can you use console to make sure if the id's are correct?

Comment: @Skarlinski The ID's are correct

Comment: But the textfield has no ID. See my answer (or all the others)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
onclick="document.getElementById(numberof'.$data2["name"].')
```

with

```
onclick="document.getElementsByName(numberof'.$data2["name"].')
```

Because there is no id for your textbox,you are using name only.So get the element by name.

You can try like this also(optionaly)

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?=$data2[\"name\"];?>" value="<?=$data2[\"name\"];?>" 
    onclick="document.getElementsByName('numberof<?=$data2[\"name\"];?>"').disabled=this.checked;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" size="1" name="numberof<?=$data2[\"name\"];?>"  value="1" " >
</td>
```

Comment: There is no property `getElementByName` in javascript it is `getElementsByName`. so there is error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using getElementById, but your textfield only uses a name and no id.

This is a quick fix:

```
<td><input type="text" size="1" id = "numberof'.$data2["name"].'" name="numberof'.$data2["name"].'"  value="1" " ></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo " 
 <td><input type='checkbox' name='".$data2['name']."' value='".$data2['name']."'
 onclick=\"document.getElementById('numberof".$data2['name']."').disabled=this.checked;\">    </td>

 <td><input type='text' size='1' id='numberof".$data2['name']."'  value='1'></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no `id` but only a `name` for the text input, you need to access it using the javascript function `getElementsByName()`.

```
onclick="document.getElementsByName(numberof'.$data2["name"].').disabled=this.checked;"></td>
```

Another mistake you have done is forgetting to enclose the name within quotes.

```
getElementById(\'numberof'.$data2["name"].'\')
```

So, your final code should look like this:

```
echo ' 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="'.$data2["name"].'" value="'.$data2["name"].'" 
onclick="document.getElementsByName(\'numberof'.$data2["name"].'\').disabled=this.checked;"></td>

<td><input type="text" size="1" name="numberof'.$data2["name"].'"  value="1" " ></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
echo ' 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="'.$data2["name"].'" value="'.$data2["name"].'" 
onclick="document.getElementsByName(\'numberof'.$data2["name"].'\')[0].disabled=this.checked;"></td>

<td><input type="text" size="1" name="numberof'.$data2["name"].'"  value="1" " ></td>';
```